# Do terms that end with 'mate' need to be clarified where people say 'mate'?

Tags: pronunciation, dialects, colloquialisms, phonetics, regional

Do terms that end with 'mate' need to be clarified where people say 'mate'?

Like while playing chess, if someone says "checkmate" in somewhere like England or Australia, is it assumed they mean "check" or "checkmate"?

Like if one would hear, "checkmate" or "check, mate". Or would they need to clarify what they mean?

Or say someone says they want some Coffee-mate, is there confusion about whether they mean coffee or Coffee-mate?

Edit: Research, I did not find any cases of confusion online, though a comment here did. Other things tend to come up in internet searches.

Edit2: I don't think that it's unlikely someone would say mate in either of these cases, people use the term a lot. Like you go up to someone and say, 'Can I have some coffee-mate'? What do they assume?

Edit3: Of course, if they couldn't differentiate, this could lead to people saying 'checkmate mate' or 'coffee-mate mate'.

Edit4: I've never noticed a significant pause when people say mate, I doubt that's the explanation.

---

**Edit note:**

Despite the fact that this got several downvotes and an answer saying that people wouldn't ever say *mate* when it could be confusing, one user with a lot of reputation gave the comment below:

> Great question! I can't answer this unfortunately, as it's been closed. The one answer you have is mistaken/wong. **This is all about tonicity.The two types of *mate* are disambiguated in speech because so-called vocatives occur after the nuclear tone/tonic syllable  when they occur at the end of a sentence, whereas the other phrases you mention would be fully stressed and actually carry the nuclear tone.**

It seems, therefore that there might be more to this interesting, well-motivated intonation question than meets the eye.

Comment: No I'm sorry, it's not clear what you are asking. Are you talking about the game of chess? If not please add an example to your question. to give us some context. "Checkmate" means "you are beaten, I've won", but "check" has multiple meanings. Have you tried usinf an BrE dictionary?

Comment: Why do you think that "checkmate" might be interpreted as "check"? Did you find that meaning listed in a dictionary? Did you see the word used with that meaning somewhere? Why do you think that the meaning might vary in different countries? Without that information, it's unclear why someone would even ask this question.

Comment: I just realized that you might be suggesting that "checkmate" could be interpreted as "check, mate" (with the second word as a vocative). If that's the case, then please edit your question to say so; it likely won't be clear to many readers as currently written.

Comment: Surely even those who routinely use *mate* as a vocative would know to resist the impulse when calling "check" in a chess game.

Comment: Great question! I can't answer this unfortunately, as it's been closed. The one answer you have is mistaken/wong. This is all about tonicity.The two types of *mate* are disambiguated in speech because so-called vocatives occur after the nuclear tone/tonic syllable  when they occur at the end of a sentence, whereas the other phrases you mention would be fully stressed and actually carry the nuclear tone.

Comment: I don't think Americans realize how much mate is said. Like how much did they say 'bro' in avatar waterworld?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. 1) reopened so please answer at length 2) what is 'tonicity'? Is it stress? or timing?

Comment: @Mitch It's the first part of the trio _tonicity tonality_ and _tone_. Tonicity concerns which syllable receives the nucleus or tonic syllable. Tonality is how an utterance is broken into different IPs (individual tunes). And tone refers to the type of pitch contour that is associated with the nucleus (and which continues to the end of the IP).

Comment: I think Mitch is asking for it to be in an answer, rather than comments

Comment: @user14094230 well yeah, in an answer is the goal here eventually, but a comment explaining is a good start. I was not aware of those technical terms in linguistics so it is good to hear them multiple times (@Araucaria is one of our local academic linguists). I will say that whoever named them needs to come up with better names... I'm already having trouble remembering which 'ton-' goes with what.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a competition. If it were, maybe it wouldn't be a debate if clear, that's the question.  I think coffee-mate is fine enough. People get the idea well enough. If you don't understand, then think of better examples.

Comment: I think the argument has been made there isn't ambiguity, no pointing needed. I'm asking about this specific case. Other words vary in other ways.

Comment: That argument has been made, but neither proven nor demonstrated to be true; the ambiguity is certainly a possibility. Otherwise, why ask the question?

Comment: I think people's experience in places where it applies would be enough proof, that's what I'm asking. The lack of  ambiguity I mentioned was mentioned in an answer, that's what the question is for.

Comment: It would be unlikely that these expressions would be used so out of context that they would be confused.

Comment: Idk people say mate a lot.

Comment: Brits don't call it a check, it's a bill, & they rarely call people they don't know 'mate'.

Comment: You would hardly ask for 'Coffee-Mate' unless you already had a cup of coffee to put it in!

Comment: Is this a joke? Are you looking for variations like "Do you have any Spotted Dick?"

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem described by the OP is so far fetched that context will eliminate ambiguity.

Comment: I'm not talking about paying for a meal, I'm talking about chess.

Comment: Are both people always sure if it's check or checkmate right away? That would be the context.

Comment: And whether someone already has coffee may not always be clear, like if there is a lid on the coffee and they want more from a different server.

Comment: And people could be familiar with servers or play chess with friends.

Comment: Since _check_ is also a chess term, I'm sure regular players must be perfectly familiar with the (theoretical) possibility of ambiguity.

Comment: Well that's the question,  if the ambiguity occurs sometimes, maybe especially for people of different experience.

Comment: Wasn't this exact same question asked a few weeks ago?

Comment: In the U.S., "check mate" might be an item on a to-do list that involved obtaining a status update on the condition of one's spouse.

Answer (score 2):

No competent English speaker is going to say "check, mate" in a context where it might be interpreted as "checkmate". You're safe interpreting checkmate as checkmate.

Comment: I had no problem finding [this](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22check+mate+you+have+to+move%22) in Google Books: *STAN: You're in **check, mate**. You have to move your king. DIRTY JOHNNY: It's not **checkmate**. STAN: I know it's not checkmate. DIRTY JOHNNY: Don't say checkmate then. Trying to fuck me up with your mind games.* But Dirty Johnny is obviously being a bit perverse - the comma reflects a spoken pause which would *always* be present when ***mate*** vocatively references the addressee, and *never* present in the one-word "chess-game-ending" ***checkmate***. No ambiguity.

Comment: @FumbleFingers that sounds like a more likely answer. But alas, people close it for lack of research, as if that was needed.

Comment: It was already closed when I came to this question. But if it hadn't been, I might well have voted to migrate it to [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). I think part of the problem is non-native Anglophones trying to learn English from the *written* form, which is obviously completely different to native speakers who are already fluent in spoken English long before they start learning how to read. So it *is* a meaningful question for non-native Anglophones, but not really for the target users here - *linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Exactly the opposite, though. It's interesting and appropriate here because intonation and phonetics are of supreme interest to linguists. This question should never have been closed. And this answer is  misleading. The two phrases *check, mate* and *checkmate* are distinguishable because of the rules about stress and tonicity in English. It is not a question of avoiding one of them in certain situations because to might be mistaken for the other. They never will be.

Comment: Yeah the case with coffee-mate, if someone is at a table and walks up to the bar and says, 'can I have some coffee-mate?', which I don't think is unlikely to say, which is assumed? 

I don't think the answer, 'people just wouldn't say that' is likely, you know how much people say mate? Like, a lot

Comment: @user14094230: I don't understand how you can still write a comment like that after having things spelled out to you, and I *really* don't understand why anyone would upvote the comment. It's ***impossible*** for native speakers to get confused about the difference between *[You're in] **check, mate*** and ***checkmate***, or *[Can I have some] **coffee, mate*** and ***Coffeemate*** because they sound completely different! Your "ambiguity" only arises because you're confusing real *spoken* language with the orthographic representation, which loses a lot of information.

Comment: That sounds like an answer then, you would then spell out how they sound different

Comment: Clearly that's a different answer than, 'people don't say that'

Comment: Yeah people say things the same all the time. 'Nineteen' and 'ninety' are obviously different things and very very important to distinguish and in articulate speech obviously have different stress/etc, but unfortunately in regular speech can easily be mistaken.  ie people 'do say that' -all- the time.

Comment: As to the particular 'check mate' problem, it'd be nice to hear how Aussies deal with it.

Comment: @Araucaria-Him Your prayer has been heard.